# Calling action from different network

Tags: nodeos, network

I am running a local blockchain on my computer. And I want to call an action on my node using eosjs from another computer in another network. My current http provider in the config section of JavaScript script is 127.0.0.1:8888, but that is applicable only to my computer. How should I know my IP address from the callers perspective? What should I put to HTTP provider instead? Are there any additional options to set when calling from another PC?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

You need a static IP for your computer where outside can find your device via this IP.

Then you should config http server from 127.0.0.1:8888 to 0.0.0.0:8888, this mean everyone can access it.

And the last thing: opening your port 8888